# what steps are needed to rewrite this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I have two functions. What steps are needed to rewrite Z1 to Z2? If possible at all?

$$ 
Z_{1}(t) = P - \frac{P\mu }{e^{\frac{P}{N}t} + \mu}
$$
$$
Z_{2}(t)= \frac{-Pe^{\frac{P}{N}t}}{\mu+e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}
$$

Comment: $Z_2=-Z_1$ using a common denominator to add the two terms in $Z_1$

Comment: The very first thing you notice is that the second term in $Z_1$ has $P\mu$ instead of $P e^{\frac{P}{N}t}$, so the first thing is to multiply $Z_2$ by a term that makes the appropriate change. After this, you probably know how to continue ...

Comment: Now I have this $$ Z_{2}(t) = \frac{e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}{\mu} \times \frac{-P\mu}{\mu + e^{\frac{P}{N}t}} $$ what is the next step to get to Z1?

Comment: thanks for the reply Matti

Answer (score 0):

$Z_{1}(t) = P - \dfrac{P\mu }{e^{\frac{P}{N}t} + \mu}$

$Z_{2}(t)= \dfrac{-Pe^{\frac{P}{N}t}}{\mu+e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}$

$\implies \dfrac{Z_{2}(t)}{e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}= \dfrac{-P}{\mu+e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}$

$\therefore Z_{1}(t) = P +\mu\cdot \dfrac{Z_{2}(t)}{e^{\frac{P}{N}t}}$

$\implies Z_2(t) = \dfrac{(Z_1(t)-P)e^{\frac PN\cdot t}}{\mu} $